# Access/Link web app from web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, web-applications

I have to make a very basic website as a final project in a intro web design class, but because I had some free time and I like programming I made a simple web application for the website. How do I access the web application from a page on the website? I've tried googling it, but I don't know if I am phrasing it correctly or not because it never returns what I am looking for.

I've been doing more research and learned that in order to access a web app I need to deploy it to the server. I haven't had time to mess around with this, so I don't know more than that, but even when it is deployed to (I would assume) the same server as my website how would I access it via a web page on the site?

Comment: Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386521.aspx),  pick your scenario, keep track of what you did and when you're stuck, [edit] your question so we have something to work with. Currently it is waaaay too broad to even start guessing what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this is the answer you were trying to find on google ,i do not full understand what you mean, but i hope this what you were looking for (got from google)Open Access, and select a web app template. (Web app templates have a picture of a globe in the background.) Tip: If you don't see the template you want, under the Search for online templates box, select Databases. Then, to find database templates on Office.com, enter one or more keywords in the search box.